# How to retrieve mapbox::util::variant value in a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, mapbox, variant

With mapbox::variant (https://github.com/mapbox/variant/blob/master/include/mapbox/variant.hpp), I can do the following:

```
using variant = mapbox::util::variant<Args...>;
variant<std::string> v;
// do something with v
...
// Get string from v:
std::string s = v.get<std::string>();
```

But when I try to implement this by a template function, I got compile error:

```
template <typename T>
T getValue()
{
    variant<T> value{};
    // Get value
    ...
    return value.get<T>();
}
```

GCC complains:

> ../utils.hpp:52:23: error: expected primary-expression before '>'
>   token
>        return value.get();
>                          ^ ../utils.hpp:52:25: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
>        return value.get();

What is wrong with the template function?

Comment: does value.template get<T>(); help?

Comment: Woops, yes, it helps. Please post it as an answer so I can mark it the correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
return value.template get<T>();
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/2325752) answer gives a good/comprehensive description as to why...